# How do I parse a list of datetimes with a 's' resolution in pandas 2?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, datetime

I have a csv with a datetime column. However, dates go all the way from 1 AD to 3000 AD. They are out of range for a normal `datetime64[ns]` dtype.

In pandas < 2, my workaround was to have this column with a "period[H]" dtype. I had a custom function doing this, which I passed as a `date_parser` in `pd.read_csv`.

In pandas >= 2, an option to have timestamps with other resolutions has been introduced. The `date_parser` argument has been deprecated, so the previous solution is also not doable. I thought I could simply cast the whole column of strings with `pd.to_datetime`.

But that doesn't work.

Full example:

`example.csv`:

```
index,date
A,"0004-04-04T12:30"
B,"2004-04-04T12:30"
C,"3004-04-04T12:30"
```

#### 1. Clueless optimism - Fails

Dates are ISO8601, easiest of the formats.

```py
df = pd.read_csv('example.csv', parse_dates=['date'])
print(df.date.dtype, '|', type(df.date.iloc[0]))
```

Got a warning:

```
<ipython-input-103-059359fbaeab>:1: UserWarning: Could not infer format, so each element will be parsed individually, falling back to `dateutil`. To ensure parsing is consistent and as-expected, please specify a format
```

And output: `object | <class 'str'>`

If `example.csv` only contains `datetime64[ns]`-valid dates, this works perfectly.

#### 2. As documented - Fails

Doc says: "read in as object and then apply to_datetime() as-needed."

```py
df = pd.read_csv('example.csv')
pd.to_datetime(df.date)
```

Fails with

```
OutOfBoundsDatetime: Out of bounds nanosecond timestamp: 0004-04-04T12:30, at position 0
```

`pd.to_datetime(df.date, unit='s')` gives :

```
ValueError: non convertible value 0004-04-04T12:30 with the unit 's', at position 0
```

so I guess the `unit` argument here doesn't have the meaning I expected.

#### 3. Per-element conversion - Partially works

```py
def to_timestamp(val):
    if pd.isna(val):
        return pd.Timestamp('NaT', unit='s')
    return pd.Timestamp(val, unit='s')
df = pd.read_csv('example.csv')
df['date'] = df.date.apply(_to_timestamp)
print(df.date.dtype, '|', type(df.date.iloc[0]))
```

Prints: `object | <class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp'>`

So indeed, the individual elements have been converted to timestamps, yay! But the column itself still has an "object" dtype, not a "datetime" one.

`df.date.astype('datetime64[s]')` fails with

```
OutOfBoundsDatetime: Cannot cast 0004-04-04 12:30:00 to unit='ns' without overflow., at position 0
```

even though I specified a "s" resolution ? Same with `pd.to_datetime(df.date)`.

#### 4. Step outside pandas - Works

```py
import numpy as np
def to_d64(val):
    if pd.isna(val):
        return np.datetime64('')
    return np.datetime64(val)

df = pd.read_csv('example.csv')
df['date'] = np.array(df.date.apply(to_d64), dtype='M8[s]')
print(df.date.dtype, '|', type(df.date.iloc[0]))
```

Success! It prints:

```
datetime64[s] | <class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp'>
```

But at what price? In the real code, my csv is thousands of lines long. The pandas < 2 code made sure to avoid converting element-per-element, as this had performance issues. I was hoping that the support for "s" resolution would be accessible directly from the string-parsing step. I also note that my final example works because my strings are in a ISO8601 format, which is support by numpy. That is not a general solution at all.

Did I miss something? Does anybody have a cleaner solution?

EDIT: I am using pandas 2.0.3 and numpy 1.24.4, Python 3.11.4 on Linux (Fedora 37).

Comment: In general, with "*thousands of lines*", I would not put optimization on top priority, unless I'd have to run the code thousands of times. Specifically, step 4 is an interesting way to sneak in seconds precision datetime... Not sure about potential side effects though. Using just `df['date'].to_numpy().astype('M8[s]')` runs ~19x faster on my machine compared to applying the `to_d64` function (iteration + branching in the function). So, if you find a way to optimize data cleanup before conversion, you might gain some performance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think `unit` in `to_datetime` only takes effect if your input is integers - but I think there is work to make it take effect even if the input is strings. Non-nanosecond support is quite new, so not yet too mature.

Anyway, here's a solution which you can use until `to_datetime` can parse non-nanosecond range strings, which involves going via `numpy` `datetime64[s]`:

```py
In [22]: data = """\
    ...: index,date
    ...: A,"0004-04-04T12:30"
    ...: B,"2004-04-04T12:30"
    ...: C,"3004-04-04T12:30"
    ...: """

In [23]: df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data))

In [24]: df['date'] = df['date'].to_numpy().astype('datetime64[s]')

In [25]: df
Out[25]:
  index                date
0     A    4-04-04 12:30:00
1     B 2004-04-04 12:30:00
2     C 3004-04-04 12:30:00
```

Comment: Thanks! This is not the answer we deserve, but it is the one that I need. I just wished, pandas was already able to do this by "conventional" means.

Comment: alternative solution: use polars, where non-nanosecond support is more mature: `polars.read_csv('example.csv', try_parse_dates=True)`